# Google Translate is not working in Edge or Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, google-translate

We have multiple sites using Google Translate. Previously, it had been working correctly on all browsers. Yesterday, when we were QCing an update on one project, we found that Google Translate was not working in Edge or Internet Explorer. When I then checked all our other projects using Google Translate, none of them worked in Edge or Internet Explorer either.

While in Edge or Internet Explorer, I can see that the Google Translate script is being loaded and the function `doGTranslate` is defined and I can run it in the console with `doGTranslate('en|es')`, but nothing on the page changes. This makes me think that the issue is on Google's side. Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Here is a basic implementation. The following code creates a language selector and properly translates the title text on every browser except Edge and Internet Explorer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Google Translate</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Page Title</h1>
  <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() { 
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'en', 
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
      }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And which version of Edge browser and IE browser are you using? Try to use F12 developer tools to check if there have some error and whether the related resource (such as google translate) load successful.

Comment: I have edited my post and added a code example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It seems that this issue is related to the Google Translate API, I have tested your code on my side, as you said, in IE and Edge browser, it will not display the DropDownList to select the language. And there is no error in IE and Edge browser if using F12 developer tools to check. So, I suggest you could post this issue to [Google Translate forum](https://support.google.com/translate/?hl=en#topic=7011755).